# I have a lot of JavaScript erorrs after SSL someone can help me?

Tags: php, css, javascript, development-strategy

I have a lot of JavaScript errors after SSL. Can someone help me?
  (https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Ffashionbymichal.com%2Fhe%2F)

Also in the console:
https://prnt.sc/qmnnzh

Answer (score 0):

First: There are no Errors, only Warnings in the W3C-Validator for your site. You should check if you can remove them, but they don't "break" your site.

The First Console Error wants you to fix the Google Font: The Font name to be used is "Assistant" not "assistant". Don't know if you can fix this yourself as you use a Premium Theme.

The second console Error is about the instagram integration. As i know nothing about this, i can not help you there.

Comment: Thanx a lot .....